# How to remove a button in a tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

The problem is that if I want to remove these buttons, which have been allocated space by x and y, it cannot be and does not generate any error or anything else shows as if it did not do any comedy, and when the button is normal it works as it should

```
import tkinter as t

root = t.Tk()

def click():
    button.pack_forget()

root.maxsize(375, 912)

img = t.PhotoImage(file="background.png")
background = t.Label(root, image=img)
background.pack()

button = t.Button(root, text ="Click\nme", command=click)
button.pack()
button.place(x=157, y=600)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't you need `place_forget()` if you expect it to be removed?

Comment: I wanted to use it later

Comment: I think the problem is that the button is placed on the background

Comment: Is there another method to set the background? because I'm only learning about tkinter

Comment: In the code sample you provided your function `def click()` is never going to do anything because you have positioned the `Button` with `place` and then call `pack_forget()`  if you want the button to be removed you have to call `place_forget`. The way you set your background image has nothing to do with this.

Comment: The real question is why are you calling 2 different geometry managers on the same widget?

Comment: and what is the difference between place and pack

Comment: because i found this in the tutorial about tkinter as you can see from the poor tutorial

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this for pack](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_pack.htm)

Comment: look at [this for place](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_place.htm)

Comment: I recommend using `pack` for simple GUI's. It's easy to learn and use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.